# can not use iai_kinect2 in ROS

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use kinect2 in ROS, firstly , I can install libfreenect2 successfully, and view normally ,According to the [turtorial](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2/blob/master/README.md) ,

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
git clone https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2.git
cd iai_kinect2
rosdep install -r --from-paths .
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"
```

I can download iai_kinect2 source code and put in right path successfully, but when I execute rosdep install -r --from-paths .
I got unexpected error ,

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-T460p:~/Faraway/src/iai_kinect2$ rosdep install -r --from-paths .
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libpcl-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-depth-image-proc
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-compressed-depth-image-transport
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-cv-bridge
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-compressed-image-transport
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
kinect2_viewer: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [kinect2_bridge]
iai_kinect2: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [kinect2_registration]
kinect2_calibration: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [kinect2_bridge]
kinect2_bridge: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [kinect2_registration]
Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-depth-image-proc
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-compressed-depth-image-transport
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libpcl-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-compressed-image-transport
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic-cv-bridge
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install ros-kinetic-depth-image-proc]
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 4, in <module>
    rosdep_main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 137, in rosdep_main
    exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 383, in _rosdep_main
    return _package_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 477, in _package_args_handler
    return command_handlers[command](lookup, packages, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 689, in command_install
    installer.install(uninstalled, **install_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/installers.py", line 520, in install
    verbose=verbose, quiet=quiet)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/installers.py", line 570, in install_resolved
    result = subprocess.call(sub_command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1392, in wait
    pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

nextly , I can not catkin_make successfully , as a result , I can not view from kinect2 in ROS ,
who does meet the same question, and how to fix it , thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285622/can-not-use-iai_kinect2-in-ros/) by [lsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/33525/lsw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-03-16**:
Did you check the 2nd note about setting correct path for libfreenect2 ?

> If you installed libfreenect2 somewhere else than in $HOME/freenect2 or a standard location like /usr/local you have to specify the path to it by adding -Dfreenect2_DIR=path_to_freenect2/lib/cmake/freenect2 to catkin_make

**Comment by [lsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/33525/lsw/) on 2018-03-16**:
thank you in advance,in fact,i meet error when i execute the command
rosdep install -r --from-paths .

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-16**:
It's most likely that you forgot to `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` before running `rosdep`.

**Comment by [lsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/33525/lsw/) on 2018-03-22**:
I am sorry , according to your suggestion I yet can not resolve the question , in the next , I plan to re-install ros kinetic version , I hope  I can solve the strange question

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-22**:
Is there a character in your password that may be interpreted as a `ctrl+c` (ie: `BREAK`)?

**Comment by [lsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/33525/lsw/) on 2018-03-22**:
yes, I press ctrl+c when pop up the following output "dpkg-query: no packages found matching libpcl-dev"  , from the words , some packages can not  be found , so there is no need to wait the whole error , I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> yes, I press ctrl+c when pop up the following output "dpkg-query: no packages found matching libpcl-dev" , from the words , some packages can not be found , so there is no need to wait the whole error

that message is not an error.

Enter your password at the prompt and press enter. Then follow the rest of the instructions printed on the console.

Things should start to work then.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0